# Barra de pesquisa tipo dinâmica que se autocompleta

Tags: jquery, mysql

Alguem poderia me ajudar em como posso fazer uma barra de pesquisa que busca com um certo delay nomes em uma coluna do mysql.

Eu tentei com o quicksearch mas não funcionou:

```html
            <!-- NOME DO CLIENTE -->
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2">
                <label class="col-3">Nome completo do cliente</label>
                <input id="consulta_cliente" type="text" class="form-control col-9" name="consulta_cliente" required minlength="5" maxlength="100">
                {% for cliente in cliente %}
                <script>
                    $('input#consulta_cliente').quicksearch('{{ cliente }}');
                </script>
                {% endfor %}
                
            </div>
```

Fiz uma query no banco de dados:

```py
    # cliente
    db = Database()
    query = "SELECT nome FROM TB_CLIENTE;"
    db.cursor.execute(query)
    cliente = db.cursor.fetchall()
```

Gostaria que funcionasse mais ou menos assim:

```
barra --> Am
Opcoes--> Amelia
          Amanda
          Am...
```

Answer (score -3):

Existe uma funcionalidade no JQuery UI para fazer autocomplete. Só precisa de ir buscar os dados uma vez no início e depois aplicar esta função no input.

```
    $( "#consulta_cliente" ).autocomplete({
      source: clientes
    });
```